# I am getting this error while placing data from data table into chart

Tags: c#, winforms

cs1503 argument 1 cannot convert from 'system.collections.generic.list <<annonymous type:string CustomerEmail,string Count>>' to "System.Collections.GenericList<Coursework.Customer>

Comment: You probably have a Lambda that creates an anonymous type instead of a new `Coursework.Customer` object (or return the object enumerated). Without code, it's hard to help you out.

Comment: i HAVE UPDATED CODE

Comment: No, you haven't.

Comment: can i mail you?

Comment: You can simply [edit](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/Editing+and+deleting+questions) this question and paste in the code

Answer (score 0):

You must map the data in the two tables together. For example, you have a product table and the product has a name and price. And you want to turn the product into a car table and the car has a name and a price. Therefore, you assign the name and price of the product to the name and price of the car table.

```
public class Product
{
  public string ProductName { get; set; }
  public string Price { get; set; }
}
public class Car
{
  public string CarName { get; set; }
  public string Price { get; set; }
}

List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
{
  new Product(){ProductName = "Car1", Price = "1,000,000"},
  new Product(){ProductName = "Car2", Price = "1,000,000"},
  new Product(){ProductName = "Car3", Price = "1,000,000"},
};


List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
foreach (var item in products)
{
   Car car = new Car();
   car.CarName = item.ProductName;
   car.Price = item.Price;
   cars.Add(car);
}

//You can now use this list...
```